# ZeroMQ : a thread stops exactly after 2 hours in a while(1)-loop. Why & how to resolve this?

Tags: multithreading, process, zeromq, qnx, qnx-neutrino

It does not crash so there is no core to analyse. It simply stops.

I have experimented multiple times. It stops exactly after 2 hours.
**OS** : qnx6.5.0
**LIBs** : ZeroMQ and Protobuf

I just have a single thread, it looks something like this :

```
dummyFrontEnd::dummyFrontEnd():context(1),socket(context,ZMQ_PUB) {

}
```

```
void dummyFrontEnd::Init()
{
    socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
    cout << "Connecting .... " << endl;
}
```

```
void dummyFrontEnd::SendCANalyserTable(const std::string& filename)
{
    ...

    zmq::message_t create_values( protoTable.ByteSizeLong()
                                + sizeof(uint16_t)
                                  );

    *((uint16_t*)create_values.data()) = TABLEMSG_ID;       // ID

    protoTable.SerializeToArray( create_values.data()
                               + sizeof(uint16_t),
                                 protoTable.ByteSizeLong()
                                 );

    try {
            socket.send(create_values,ZMQ_NOBLOCK);
           }
    catch (int e){
            std::cout << "SPD exception e : "
                      <<  e
                      << std::endl;
           }

    protoTable.clear_columnvalues();
    usleep(1);

    }

}
```

```
void main(){
...

...
  while(1) {
    if (arguments.canalyser_filename != "") {
        dmyFntEnd.SendCANalyserTable(arguments.canalyser_filename);

        if (arguments.verbose) {
            cout << "DummyFrontEnd"
                 << "completed sending CANalyser table"
                 <<  endl;
        }
    }
  }
...
...
}
```

Comment: Would you mind to post the ZeroMQ version ( major#,  minor#, patch# ). Thank you.

Comment: You could be reaching the "high water mark" because you are sending data faster than it is received. Or it is no longer received at all. I would expect your program to block or hang in this case, not "stop", unless you have some custom terminate or unhandled exception handler.

Comment: Do you have a `while(1)` loop in your thread **and** in your `main()`?

Comment: @rveerd the hypothesis with **`SND_HWM`** is not supported from the published ZeroMQ API documentation. The **`ZMQ_PUB`** Archetype simply drops any new items **`.send()`**-ing tries to enqueue, so no, this is not the root cause of the problem.

Comment: @ user3666197  thanks for replying  to my questions , it gave me more clarity .ZeroMQ version is 4.3.2

Comment: @rveerd data speed is  1 data per millisecond.  at the end when I check the receiver log , its received all the data transmitted. I have a while (1) only in my main

Comment: @user3666197  I found the root cause for this problem. 
I was ssh'ing into the qnx box off VPN.  and used to start the binary as ./flightrecorder 
This command got bound to my terminal session. I was loosing my session every two hours . so the binary also stopped . 
Now I am running it as ./flightrecorder &  --> this unassociate the binary with my terminal session . 
With the above change , the binary is running for many hours now

this link was helpful . 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4004/how-can-i-run-a-command-which-will-survive-terminal-close

Thanks

Comment: **`nohup process &`** got me `:o)` **Anyway, stay tuned** ... the last case with connection drop I recall with GSM-operator mobile modem connections, they forgot to delete a configuration line for 120 minute forced connection-drop for data-services. That obscure setting was required by the TELCO-regulator to "protect" voice-service consumers ( ROFL ) ... *somewhere deep back in 90-ies*